# How do I modify the responsiveness of my page for mobile view on AppDrag?

Tags: css, content-management-system

I finished creating my landing page, and now I would like to amend the font sizes and padding/margin for the mobile view.

Is there a way to do that using the visuals as opposed to going into the source code?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're in the mobile view, which is by selecting from the top bar of the pagebuilder, whatever changes you make there will only take effect in that view.  In regards to the responsive text size, there is an additional button in the toolbar called Responsive Text, where you will be able to make changes to the text's responsiveness.